# PyOpenCL: gl sharing context creation failed (overflow error)

Tags: python, opengl, opencl, pyopengl, pyopencl

I want to create an application that uses OpenCL to caluculate the color value of every pixel in a texture and OpenGL to display that texture. The problem is that when I try to create a context with GL sharing properties the program freezes. Using the function `get_gl_sharing_context_properties()` I get a list `[(8200, 65538), (8203, 18446744072971422270)]`. The last number in the list is too big to convert to a 64 bit int and I get an overflow error. 
The code I use to create the CL context:

```
def cl_init():
    platform = cl.get_platforms()[1]
    device = platform.get_devices(cl.device_type.GPU)

    from pyopencl.tools import get_gl_sharing_context_properties

    print(cl.have_gl())
    print(get_gl_sharing_context_properties())
    print(sys.platform)
    context = cl.Context(properties=[
                (cl.context_properties.PLATFORM, platform)] +
                get_gl_sharing_context_properties())

    print("Context creation done")

    queue = cl.CommandQueue(context)
```

The code never reaches `print("Context creation done")`. I use QtPy4 and the QGLWidget to create the OpenGL context and display the texture.

Comment: Were you ever able to get this to run? I am running into the same issue right now. What is making is especially frustrating is that sometimes, `get_gl_sharing_context_properties()` returns a valid 64bit value, but other times, it will randomly fail...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok ran into a similar issue myself and here is my fix for it. If you look exactly at what `get_gl_sharing_context_properties()` is doing according to [PyOpenCL's source code on github](https://github.com/pyopencl/pyopencl/blob/58896e20bcefb83ca5bfc19ddf3e1fce625a3c10/pyopencl/tools.py) under the `tools` module, you will find the following platform-specific code:

```
def get_gl_sharing_context_properties():
    ctx_props = cl.context_properties

    from OpenGL import platform as gl_platform

    props = []

    import sys
    if sys.platform in ["linux", "linux2"]:
        from OpenGL import GLX
        props.append(
            (ctx_props.GL_CONTEXT_KHR, gl_platform.GetCurrentContext()))
        props.append(
                (ctx_props.GLX_DISPLAY_KHR,
                    GLX.glXGetCurrentDisplay()))
    elif sys.platform == "win32":
        from OpenGL import WGL
        props.append(
            (ctx_props.GL_CONTEXT_KHR, gl_platform.GetCurrentContext()))
        props.append(
                (ctx_props.WGL_HDC_KHR,
                    WGL.wglGetCurrentDC()))
    elif sys.platform == "darwin":
        props.append(
            (ctx_props.CONTEXT_PROPERTY_USE_CGL_SHAREGROUP_APPLE,
                cl.get_apple_cgl_share_group()))
    else:
        raise NotImplementedError("platform '%s' not yet supported"
                % sys.platform)

    return props
```

Now, since I am on Windows, I took a look at the WGL code (which comes from `PyOpenGL`) and found that `WGL.wglGetCurrentDC()` (like `get_gl_sharing_context_properties()` of course) was returning incorrect handle values sometimes that caused the integer overflow. It turns out the DC (device context) is really *supposed* to be a **32 bit signed integer**. However, in the `PyOpenGL` wrapper function, it is being converted wrongly to a **64 bit unsigned integer**. As a result, whenever a negative DC handle value is passed into PyOpenGL, it is being converted to become `2^64 + annoying_negative_dc_number` instead!

The solution: convert it back! Here is what I now do to reliably get a working gl interop context:

```
platform = cl.get_platforms()[0]
ctx_props = cl.context_properties
gl_props = get_gl_sharing_context_properties()
device_context = gl_props[-1][-1]
if device_context >= 2 ** 32:
    device_context -= (2 ** 64)
fixed_gl_props = [gl_props[0], (gl_props[-1][0], device_context)]
ctx = cl.Context(properties=[(ctx_props.PLATFORM, platform)] + fixed_gl_props)
```

Answer (score 0):

There's a bug in pyopencl that causes the context creation to be incorrectly handled. Essentially, pyopencl takes a list of tuples for the opencl properties and internally parses them and passes them to the CL context creation handler. The tuples are either passed as pointers or integers. When pointers are passed for certain properties, it is suppose to convert the pointer to an integer value to pass to the CL context creation handler, but it does this incorrectly. Instead it grabs the address of the pointer itself.

There are two possible fixes.

From the user code side, you could do something like the following to manually pass the integer value for broken properties such as GLX_DISPLAY_KHR. Or you could approach the issue by picking apart the tuples returned from get_gl_sharing_context_properties() and correcting them:

```
    glx_addr = ctypes.cast(OpenGL.GLX.glXGetCurrentDisplay(), ctypes.c_void_p).value #retrieve the glx ptr val as an int
    context = cl.Context(properties=
        [(cl.context_properties.GL_CONTEXT_KHR, OpenGL.platform.GetCurrentContext() )] +
        [(cl.context_properties.GLX_DISPLAY_KHR, glx_addr )] +
        [(cl.context_properties.PLATFORM, cl.get_platforms()[0])]
    )
```

Or within cffi_cl.py src code of pyopencl fix the bug itself and recompile:

```
def _parse_context_properties(properties):
    ...
    from ctypes import _Pointer, addressof
    from ctypes import cast # add this

    if isinstance(value, _Pointer):
        #val = addressof(value) # remove this
        val = cast(value, ctypes.c_void_p).value # add this
    else:
        val = int(value)
    ...
```

I communicated this bug to the developer, a little bit ago so hopefully it will be fixed soon. See: https://lists.tiker.net/pipermail/pyopencl/2017-April/002285.html